# Is it possible to get access to Google Play Developer API using Service Account flow?

Tags: google-oauth

Is it possible to get access to Google Play Developer API using Service Account flow?
Documentation here (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization) mentions only OAuth 2.0 Web Server flow. But it's unclear whether it is example or restriction.

If it is possible it will be great for some link to working example to be provided. Cause I wasn't able to get past "This developer account does not own the application" response.

Answer (score 1):

It is **possible** to access the Google Play Developer API using Service Account flow.

---

[Official sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/) shows how to authorize with Service Account using `service account email` and `p12 file`.
The [relevant credential creating code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/blob/master/v3/java/src/com/google/play/developerapi/samples/AndroidPublisherHelper.java#L95-L109) looks as following:

```
private static Credential authorizeWithServiceAccount(String serviceAccountEmail)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    log.info(String.format("Authorizing using Service Account: %s", serviceAccountEmail));
    // Build service account credential.
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountEmail)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(
                    Collections.singleton(AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER))
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(SRC_RESOURCES_KEY_P12))
            .build();
    return credential;
}
```

Folks at AzimoLabs wrote a [post](https://medium.com/azimolabs/review-reporter-part-1-connecting-to-google-play-8abd37edc49f) where they retrieving store reviews using this method. They also [open-sourced](https://github.com/AzimoLabs/Review-Reporter) their tool.

---

You can also authorize with Service Account using JSON key type:

```
private static Credential authorizeWithServiceAccount() throws IOException {
    log.info("Authorizing using Service Account");
    try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(JSON_PATH)) {
        return GoogleCredential.fromStream(fileInputStream, HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY)
                .createScoped(Collections.singleton(AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER));
    }
}
```

More detailed instructions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48239154/1233652).

Comment: Finally! ;) It's a bit outdated question through. It seems that Google had fixed the problem I was hitting back in 2013. A few years later there was much less problem with backend authorization...